# Sitecore Personalize Preview not working

Tags: sitecore-personalize

I am working on a POC for a potential client using the sandbox that Sitecore has provided. This is for a **localhost** Sitecore website.
Here are the steps:

1. I created an alert banner that should appear at the top of the site.
2. I added the following code to my solution and published my code successfully. However, when I preview the site through the personalize dashboard, the alert banner does not show. What I might be missing?

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Define the Boxever queue
    var _boxeverq = _boxeverq || [];
    // Define the Boxever settings
    var _boxever_settings = {
        client_key: '<<I used the key provided by Sitecore>>', // Replace with your client key
        target: 'https://api-us.boxever.com/v1.2', // Replace with your API target endpoint specific to your data center region
        cookie_domain: '{{cookieDomain}}', // Replace with the top level cookie domain of the website that is being integrated e.g ".example.com" and not "www.example.com"
        javascriptLibraryVersion: '1.4.8', // Replace with the latest Boxever JavaScript Library version"
        pointOfSale: '<<POS>>', // Replace with the same point of sale configured in system settings" (I created this POS in the Personalize System Settings)
        web_flow_target: 'https://d35vb5cccm4xzp.cloudfront.net', // Replace with path for the Amazon CloudFront CDN for Sitecore Personalize"
        web_flow_config: { async: false, defer: false } // Customize the async and defer script loading attributes
    };

    // Import the Boxever JavaScript Library asynchronously
    (function() {
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true;
        s.src = 'https://d1mj578wat5n4o.cloudfront.net/boxever-1.4.8.min.js';
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
    </script>
   ```

**UPDATE** :
Error in the network tab: I have used the key that Sitecore provided. The same key is in the Personalize System Settings as well

```
{
"version": "1.2",
"status": "UNAUTHORIZED",
"error_msg": "Invalid client key specified",
"moreInfo": "mailto:support@sitecore.com",
"clientKey": "[[Key]]"
}
```

Comment: Check this -https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30886/why-is-preview-not-working-in-my-web-experience-experiment-in-sitecore-personali

Comment: Also check the console if there is any error. POS name should match the configured value.

Comment: have you checked the debug panel to make sure that your conditions have been met to show the alert banner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script looks good.
Please check the following things:

- Is Boxever available? Check e.g. Boxever.browser_id in your console.
- Does your POS match the one you configured in Sitecore CDP? ´
- Does your cookieDomain match this: '*.yourwebsite.com'?
- When you open the preview on your website, if the QA tool appears on the left, can you check that?
- If it does not appear here is the trick to call it: Call your website with the missing queryparams: https://www.yourwebsite.com/?bxQATool=true&bxFlowRef=your-experience-id . The experience ID you can copy from the url when you open your experience in Sitecore CDP.
  The QA tool should give you a hint, what might be wrong.

It would be good if you could share with us what you set up in Sitecore CDP.

Comment: Thank you  - I do see an error in the N/W tab which I have added to the original post. The POS does match the one I configured. I had left the cookieDomain as it is optional. I did try the trick as well, but the QA toolbox doesn't show up. Maybe it is because of the 401 error which I am getting

Comment: It's saying your clientKey is wrong - Can you re-check that?

Comment: Ah you said you re-checked that. 
I am not sure if we can help you if the Client Key in Sitecore CDP - System Settings > API Access and in your script are the same. Is the "API Token Active" setting set to ON or OFF?

Comment: API Token Active was on - I changed it to off, same error (401)
One question - Boxever.browser_id comes back as anonymous. Is that expected/

Comment: I would make sure that you are using the correct API Url for the target.  You mentioned using api-us.boxever.com, which would mean that you login with https://app-us.boxever.com to access your tenant, is that the case?  That would be a potential reason why the client key is invalid, since those are defined per data center.  The API Token toggle should not affect using the Stream APIs.

Comment: That did it, thank you!